# 404 status on XMLHTTP with VBA, but the URL is opening in browser

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get some information from a website, but I get the status 404, even though the url opens correctly in any browser window.
This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub GetURL()

Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Url = "http://sklep.trefl.com/en/puzzle.html#price%5Bfrom%5D=0&price%5Bto%5D=9999999&p=1&limit=30"

With xhr
    .Open "GET", Url, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
    .send
    If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        wtext = .responseText
    Else
        Debug.Print "error"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

What could be the problem?
I've tried with and without https.
I've also tryed encoding the "#" charcter to "%23".

Thanks!

Comment: Had you checked if it is blocked by CORS?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try without "`#price%5Bfrom%5D=0&price%5Bto%5D=9999999&p=1&limit=30`"? - Just "`http://sklep.trefl.com/en/puzzle.html`" and you will get the correct status code.

```
Sub GetURL()

Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Url As String

Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Url = "http://sklep.trefl.com/en/puzzle.html"

With xhr
    .Open "GET", Url, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
    .send
    If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        wtext = .responseText
    Else
        Debug.Print "error"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Anyway you can get the content for this URL (`http://sklep.trefl.com/en/puzzle.html#price%5Bfrom%5D=0&price%5Bto%5D=9999999&p=1&limit=30`). Check this:

```
...
    Else
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End If
...
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but I can only get the first page, the parameters p and limit would allow me to get the other pages. How could I get the next pages?

Comment: You will try these URLs: `http://sklep.trefl.com/en/Filter/advanced/result/?dir=asc&id=38&limit=30&order=position&p=1&price%5Bfrom%5D=0&price%5Bto%5D=9999999`, `http://sklep.trefl.com/en/Filter/advanced/result/?dir=asc&id=38&limit=30&order=position&p=2&price%5Bfrom%5D=0&price%5Bto%5D=9999999` and so on. Besides this, for these URLs (without #) you will get the correct status codes.

Comment: Parameters proceeded with # require browser to process them. You can use Urls like this: http://sklep.trefl.com/en/Filter/advanced/result/?price[from]=0&price[to]=9999999&p=2&limit=30